# Linux VPS extremely slow

Tags: server, 18.04

Good day,

I rent 2 VPS servers. The last few days 1 of the rented VPS servers is extremely slow. It takes about 2 to 3 minutes to open a simple webpage or PLESK.

I have tried to do multiple things to speed it up but nothing helps.
I tried to reinstall updates (plesk), i tried to block visitors from russia and china (but i am not allowed to do that via csf (configServer) because it wants to add more ip's than allowed), and i rebooted the server several times.

These are the specs from 1 of the servers (other one is slower)

https://www.strato.nl/server/vps-linux/ -> V30

```
$ lscpu
Architecture:        x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):      32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:          Little Endian
CPU(s):              0
Vendor ID:           GenuineIntel
CPU family:          6
Model:               45
Model name:          Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2630 0 @ 2.30GHz
Stepping:            7
CPU MHz:             1999.584
BogoMIPS:            4600.28
Virtualization:      VT-x
Hypervisor vendor:   Parallels
Virtualization type: container
Flags:               fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf eagerfpu pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx smx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid dca sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx lahf_lm epb ssbd ibrs ibpb stibp tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid xsaveopt dtherm ida arat pln pts spec_ctrl intel_stibp flush_l1d
```

Memory:

```
# free
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:        8388608      514300     6135724       68608     1738584     2023925
Swap:             0           0           0
```

Where can i start to figure out why it is so slowly?
Thanks for everyones help

Comment: I will advice you to install `htop` or another like that to see which services/processes are using the cpu/ram, and also benchmark the disk. If you have a similar setup on the non-slow vps, you can compare the things that are running. Way back i faced a similar issue, and at the end was a malware/virus using almost all my cpu/network.

Comment: Thanks, i will try tomorrow but now my other vps is also slow so maybe it is their fault. I will ask again tomorrow because i feel i can’t fix it

Comment: did you solve the problem ?

Comment: No, other than changing to another company for webhosting. Since then i have 0 problems